# ¿Cómo incrementar las letras, de la A a la Z, en un bucle?

Tags: php, javascript, bucle-for, while

Me parece haber visto (en un manual) que sí se puede hacer esto, pero no recuerdo cómo. Estaba pensando en que quizá cada letra tenga su valor numérico, algo así como las entidades html (o su representación binaria), de esa forma podría escribir la letra como dígitos en el bucle y así poder incrementarla.

Comment: Hola, en php eso se puede hacer con un simple `++`, puedes revisar este ejemplo en la documentación oficial https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.increment.php#example-131

Comment: Sí, esto es lo que había visto en el manual. No sé cómo se me olvidó. Gracias. Aun así, me parece interesante haber aprendido a hacerlo con el método "chr", porque esto también sirve para java script, aunque claro, con el método de js correspondiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la codificación de los caracteres que recorra el abecedario según su código de caracteres.

ejemplo.

```
for($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {  
$letra = chr($i);  
echo '<a href="index.php?letra='.$letra.'">'.$letra.'</a> | ';  }
```

Te dejo unas documentaciones, aqui puedes ver los códigos ASCII ( elcodigoascii.com.ar ) y en la documentacion de php menciona que chr — Devuelve un caracter específico por ascii (php.net/manual/es/function.chr.php).

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿que hace exactamente el metodo "chr"? ¿convierte codigos decimales en letras?....¿y como puedo saber que numero o codigo le pertenece a cada letra?

Comment: Te dejo unas documentaciones, aqui puedes ver los códigos ASCII ( https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/ )  y en la documentacion de php menciona que chr — Devuelve un caracter específico por ascii (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.chr.php)

Comment: .......gracias.